# Using Typeahead with SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, typeahead.js

I am attempting to use Typeahead with my SignalR implementation.
What is happening is my Hub is getting hit and returning the value, but my `result` after `.done()` is `undifined`. I cannot work out why?

Javascript

```
$(function () {

    var search = $.connection.searchHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        $('#searchBar').typeahead(null, {
            minLength: 2,

            // begin source      
            source: function (query, process) {
                var suggestions = [];// my callback value


                search.server.search(query)
                        .done(function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                            $.each(result, function () {
                                console.log(result);
                                suggestions.push(this);
                                process(suggestions);//process is a callback method
                            });
                        }).fail(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                            process([]);//process is a callback method, don't know if this is necessary here, but will produce no suggestions
                        });
            }
        });

    });
```

Hub:

```
[HubName("searchHub")]
    public class SearchHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task Search(string query)
        {
            api = new MovieApi();
            var result = await api.Search(query);

            if (result.results != null)
            {
                Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).results(result.results[0].title);
            }
            else
            {
                Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).noResults("There are no search results!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search method does not return anything so its not strange that its undefined. You need to change to `Task<T>` and return something

Also I can not see that you are subscribing to `results` or `noResults`? Like

```
search.client.results = function(result) {
   console.log(result);
};
```

edit: Also its very strange to use SIgnalR for this, standard REST with request/response should be fine here

Comment: You could use the hub for this in the same way you do with WebAPI but here he uses push.